# How to make a execute a task periodicly in time?

Tags: android, multithreading, scheduled-tasks

Hi I want to know how to make a task execute over time and stop it. I have tried Thread.Sleep() and it did not work. So basically here is my idea I want to execute a task every 5 seconds and then stop repeating it.

Start the task - when activity is created.

Execute task

Wait 5 seconds

Execute task again

...

Activity closed

Task does not execute anymore.

Comment: use a handler or a timer task.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use TimerTask as below

```
Timer t = new Timer();
    TimerTask task = new TimerTask() {
        @Override
        public void run() {

    runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            // Do your stuff

        }
    });


        }
    };
    t.scheduleAtFixedRate(task, 1000, 5000);
```

at onDestry

```
t.cancel()
```

Comment: I get error -  Cant create Handler inside thread that has not called looper properly

Comment: inside run I am calling a function that gets the current coordinates (Longitude and Latitude)

Answer (score 1):

You could try this:

```
Timer timer = new Timer();
TimerTask tt = new TimerTask() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        yourTaskMethod();
    }
};
timer.scheduleAtFixedRate(tt, 0L, 5000L);
```

**UPDATE :**
If u plan to use main elements in that method like `Toast` or something else u should use :

```
public void yourTaskMethod() {
    //simple elements that don't need main thread
    int a = b+c;
    // for elements that use main thread
    runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            Toast...
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: Can't create handler inside thread that has not called Looper.prepare()

Answer (score 0):

If you only want to execute tasks while your activity is open, the easiest way is to use a Timer. See [here](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/Timer.html) for description of Timer.

Comment: I agree it is the easiest way I use the code as cosmincalistru suggested but I get an error:
 Cant create Handler inside thread that has not called looper properly

Answer (score 0):

You can [Schedule Repeating Alarms](http://developer.android.com/training/scheduling/alarms.html).

```
Intent intent = new Intent(this, TestService.class);
PendingIntent pintent = PendingIntent.getService(this, 0, intent, 0);
AlarmManager alarm = (AlarmManager) getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);

alarm.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, cal.getTimeInMillis(),5000, pintent);   // 5000 means 5 second
```

TestService.java

```
public class TestService extends Service 
{
     @Override
     public void onCreate() 
     {
              // TODO Auto-generated method stub

              Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Service Created", 1).show();
             super.onCreate();
     }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

final Thread myTask = new Thread(
  new Runnable() {
    public void run() {
      int count = 0;
      while (count <= 1) {
        // Do whatever you need
        ...
        count++;
        System.sleep(5000);           // 5 seconds
      }
    }
  } 
).start();

Answer (score 0):

Check out the documentation on Alarm Manager - that helped me a lot.

Answer (score 0):

Use [Alarm Manager](http://developer.android.com/training/scheduling/alarms.html)  it s the standard way in android

Answer (score 0):

Use runnable thread and start it using a handler... by handler.postDelayed(runnable, 5*1000).... 
Call the same statement inside the run method of runnable....